# Excel how to count the number of same words/ strings in a excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel sheet with data in rows for example:

```
    aa
    aabbcc
    aa, aa aa
    aabbcc
    dd, dd
    ee
```

So I am looking for an output like : aa = 4, aabbcc = 2 , dd=2, ee=1 .

Comment: programming language?

Comment: @Sachin: cant we do within excel? using formulas.

Comment: Use `COUNTIFS`?

Comment: Would you ever get a string like AAABBC and if so, what then?

Answer (score 1):

My solution was using **=Countif('Form Responses 1'!C:C,"aa")**

would count all instances of aa. Now would that include aabbcc? I'm not sure. If so there may be a way to refine this. Usually when I need to do this it is to separate two answers such as Yes or No to questions asked. Because there is no similiarities in the answers, I don't run into issues with them. Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. Search A1 value

```
=IIF(SEARCH(A1,"aabbcc")>0;SUBSTITUTE(A1;"aabbcc";"2");IIF(SEARCH(A1,"aa")>0;SUBSTITUTE(A1;"aa";"4");IIF(SEARCH(A1,"dd")>0;SUBSTITUTE(A1;"dd";"2");IIF(SEARCH(A1,"ee")>0;SUBSTITUTE(A1;"ee";"1");""))))
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Supports](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213889). You may try this. (This is an array formula so you will have to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when entering the formula into the cell otherwise you will get a #VALUE error)

```
=SUM(LEN(range)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(range,"text","")))/LEN("text")
```

where range is the cell range in question and "text" is replaced by the specific text string that you want to count.

Answer (score 0):

If each cell had a unique item you could create next to column A in column B a column of only 1s, then I would highlight the data and press CTRL+T to put the data into a table. Then I would click the insert tab and insert pivot table and that will give you the amount of each thing. This pivot table will then produce a list for you of all the unique items and the amount of occurrences.

However since this is not the case here is the solution for defining a word as ending at a comma or space for your particular problem.
Make sure you press Ctrl+Shift+Enter

```
="aa = "&SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$6&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$6&" ",","," "),"aa ","")))/LEN("aa ")
="aabbcc = "&SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$6&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$6&" ",","," "),"aabbcc ","")))/LEN("aabbcc ")
="dd = "&SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$6&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$6&" ",","," "),"dd ","")))/LEN("dd ")
="ee = "&SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$6&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$6&" ",","," "),"ee ","")))/LEN("ee ")
```

This should give you the exact output you asked for in 4 different cells, you could combine this output into 1 cell by putting them all together with & such as this.. copy and paste this and it should give you the exact output you were looking for.

```
="aa = "&SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$6&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$6&" ",","," "),"aa ","")))/LEN("aa ")&", "&"aabbcc = "&SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$6&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$6&" ",","," "),"aabbcc ","")))/LEN("aabbcc ")&", "&"dd = "&SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$6&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$6&" ",","," "),"dd ","")))/LEN("dd ")&", "&"ee = "&SUM(LEN($A$1:$A$6&" ")-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A$1:$A$6&" ",","," "),"ee ","")))/LEN("ee ")
```

Comment: thats the problem , i have text separated by commas and spaces

Comment: The above array formula provided by Sachin is the only way I can think of accomplishing this with regular Excel functions, the only problem is his solution produces aa=5 instead of the 4 you expected. This is because it seems there is no built in function to distinguish a space or a comma as a new word. It looks like you may have to resort to VBA as the commas and spaces add a new level of complexity. I'm still looking into how this can be done with the built in functions without it being too huge of an equation.

Comment: It is possible to exploit the particular nature of the example data so that Sachin's method produces the expected result. Strip out the commas by substitution and then append a space at the end of the string in each cell. Use "text"&" " in place of "text" in his formula, and voila! (I put together a set of tryingly complicated formulas that also do the job, but it hardly seems worth the trouble in the face of such brevity.)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions so far seem to have some deficiencies (no lack of effort and ingenuity! - I fear Excel was never really designed for such a requirement) so I would suggest exporting to Word, if the quantity is substantial, in conjunction with word-frequency usage from a concordance program (eg [Simple Concordance Program](http://www.textworld.com/scp)).

Alternatively, in Word replace pilcrows (paragraph markers) and commas with spaces, and multiple adjacent spaces with just one, then to create a single column of values (with Insert > Tables - Table) for reimport into Excel, extraction of a list of uniques, and application of a formula to that list.

Answer (score -1):

A variation on the Countif approach is to specify wildcards as part of the search string.  * can be used to substitute for many characters, ? for single characters.  This enables you to count the no of occurrences irrespective of the position of the string in the text of a range of cells.

Comment: This would be better as a comment, not an answer.